# What was the first time the '@' at sign was used to address an user?

Tags: computers

The first app I know to use "@" to address people is Twitter and then it caught on. I know that "@" was used in Usenet as a replacement for the word "at", but not to refer to specific users to my knowledge.

Edit: 
I am not referring to just using the @ at symbol in general. I am aware of this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign

I am asking for the first time the symbol was used to refer to a specific person or user. **For example, @Jane** and NOT jane@email.com.

Did Twitter invent this usage when it was founded in 2006? And if so, who made that decision?

Comment: It was part of the original ARPANET standard in the 1970;s's: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Internet

Comment: Upvoted to offset downvote.  The question is about recent history, but as Pieter's comment shows, it has an answer.  Why downvote or close a legitimate question that has a discernible answer?

Comment: Because questions that can be answered by wikipedia should be closed as described in [ask]

Comment: I did and didn't find my answer. Wikipedia answers the first known usage but I'd like to know the first time it was used to refer to usernames.

Comment: Well this can't be answered because it's been put on hold instead of migrated to stack overflow; but having `@` as part of a username is a byproduct on using email addresses as a unique identifier for a user account. Prior to the web, usernames were server specific and thus no login asked for the `@somwhere` component as this was implicit.

Comment: You may find [this audio article](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=120364591) relevant to your question. It credits Ray Tomlinson, the inventor of email as first using the @ symbol as an addressing glyph. He refers to it as "the only preposition on the keyboard".

Comment: I think an edit distinguishing between "joe@ibm.com" which is easily discoverable and just @joe which is not might help this question. Several communities seemed to adopy the convention at once, and it's the **opposite** of how it's done with email addresses.

Comment: I can tell you that on Usenet (I used it heavily and wrote a book about it) nobody said @Kate to address a person.

Comment: @KateGregory Thank you for the suggestion and your comment. I edited the post.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the on-hold reason here. This is not trivia easily obtained from a wiki...

Comment: I am confused as to what you mean by "used to refer to a specific person". Are you asking for *the first time* someone used @<name> to **address a person** (e.g. like your @KateGregory in your last comment)? If so your Usenet sentence is contradictory and confusing. It has been a long time since @ became a symbol for "at" (at least in some circles) and definitely predates Twitter.

Comment: @Semaphore yes, exactly. I am referring to @<name> like in this comment. I am not sure how to reword it to make it less confusing. I mentioned Usenet to make it clear that I have researched the usage of the At symbol but I couldn't find my specific answer.

Comment: @RommelTJ I made an edit to clarify the question based on what you said. However, I don't expect a definitive answer is possible... it was probably first used around the time people started using @ to mean "at"...

Comment: Might be better at ELU; those folks are good at digging up historical language use.

Comment: in fact it's been done: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/42639/3946 though there is a not a really great answer so far.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if here was the best place for this question but ELU also doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not trivia when noone knows the answer.